# clear all docker data for a clean restart

Tags: docker

I'm running a docker image of [nocodb](https://www.nocodb.com/) on my macbook. I chose the sqlite version. Everything works. I have made some projects and tables to test. After testing, I want to reset all this. I stopped and deleted the container, but after starting a new container, all the previous projects and tables... are still there. I want a clean restart. I tried to delete all volumes, I deleted the nocodb image and downloaded it again, but it seems like the sqlite db is somewhere on my laptop.

What I want to achieve: when I stop and delete a docker container, I want to be able to delete all associated data, so that when I restart the container, it starts from the beginning.

To run container:

```
ocker run -d --name nocodb \
-v "$(pwd)"/nocodb:/usr/app/data/ \
-p 8080:8080 \
nocodb/nocodb:latest
```

To stop/delete container:

```
docker stop <ID>
docker rm <ID>
docker system prune
```

Comment: What command are you using to delete the volumes? What command are you using to run your containers? Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are storing your data in `$(pwd)/nocodb` with this command:

```
docker run -d --name nocodb \
  -v "$(pwd)"/nocodb:/usr/app/data/ \
  -p 8080:8080 \
  nocodb/nocodb:latest
```

To reset, you'll need to delete the persistent data in that directory.

Answer (score 1):

Your data is stored in `$(pwd)/nocodb`. You'll need to delete this directory.

Alternatively for Docker volumes:

Running `docker system prune` does **NOT** remove volumes, for this you need to add the `--volumes` option. Be careful with this command, as it will delete **ALL** volumes, including those you might want to keep.

To delete only one specific Docker volume run `docker volume rm <VOLUME NAME>`.

To delete all unused volumes (unused volumes are volumes that are not referenced by any containerts) run `docker volume prune`.